# New controller directories in codeigniter serves 404

Tags: codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-404

I have directories under my controller directory that serve perfectly.  However, creating any new directories on that level results in a 404 every single time.  All I am doing is echoing hello world.  I believe it is a directory issue at this point.  Privileges are the same as the directories that are working as well as the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `.htaccess` in the `/application` directory of CodeIgniter which prevents you from accessing files within that directory directly.

This is done be design so that none has direct access to your code. You should consider not deviating from this.

Comment: Fair enough, but because there are no restrictions that doesn't explain the issue.  Also, it doesn't explain why previous directories are working.

Comment: Okay, do you have file names that conflict with your directory?

Comment: No sir.  For example, I have /controllers/deactivation and all files work in that directory.  I created /controllers/test and no files work in that one.

Comment: Okay, this requires a little more debugging than the simple Q&A, can you post the exact directory structure?

Comment: /application/controllers/crons/test.php (where I am echoing hello world but 404's)
/application/controllers/deactivation/test.php (this one actually serves the hello world)

Comment: Interesting, do you have anything in `routes.php` that could cause it to 404? Also, can you set `log_threshold` in `config.php` to `4`?

Comment: nothing is in routes.php.  After setting the logging to 4 the application breaks...

Comment: so i found the issue.  I am guessing there is in fact an htaccess file...somewhere because putting an index.php in front of the controller works.

Thanks so much.